# iOS: how to decide if device supports AV scanner?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, video-capture, barcode-scanner

I have a scanner functionality in the my iOS app (a universal app).

In order to hide the scanner UI on old iPods which only have front camera, I use the following code before showing the scanner UI:

```
+ (BOOL)isScannerSupported {

    AVCaptureDevice *defaultVideoDevice = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];

    BOOL result = (defaultVideoDevice.position == AVCaptureDevicePositionBack);

    return result;
}
```

This worked quite well so far, as any modern iPhone or iPad returned YES for this method.

However, I just got an email from a customer using iPad Pro 9.7 model A1673 (iOS 11.2.1) who claims that scanner functionality isn't displayed.

This probably means that the position in the above method isn't AVCaptureDevicePositionBack (must be AVCaptureDevicePositionFront, or AVCaptureDevicePositionUnspecified).

Can anyone explain this anomaly? Is the logic of the method is simply incorrect?

Comment: try to toggle the camera to front ,  see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16591918/ios-toggle-avfoundation-camera

Comment: I'm not showing any toggle button in my app. To which toggle button you refer to?

Comment: Toggle it in code If you can't find a back Camera in Ipad pro and vice versa

Comment: Do you understand why defaultDeviceWithMediaType returns a different value than AVCaptureDevicePositionBack on the iPad Pro? What can affect  the default device?

Comment: possibly a bug , try this as a workaround

Comment: Thanks for helping